# C# - WebRequest: Too many automatic redirections were attempted

Tags: c#, redirect, cookies

I have a problem with the automatic redirects while using the class WebRequest.
I create a simple application that can log in (using login and password) to the website and download some contents.

I read that a common reason is the lack of CookieContainer. In my case, everything works fine until the cookies are turned off. Then the redirections works well, but - in this way - I will never logged in to my account (I don't support cookies)... when I try to turn on cookies, I receive a communicate: "too many redirects" - but it isn't true. Log in to the web application requires exactly two redirects - I know it and I checked my opinion. It isn't the bug of webpage application.

The source code:

```
private string DoGETrequest(string url)
    {
        // settings
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
        //

        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;


        request.Method = "GET";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        Uri responseUri = response.ResponseUri;

        var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

        return responseString;
    }
```

I would like to avoid the problem with maximum amount of redirections and as well as accept the cookies, that is necessary to login.
The best solution is using WebRequest, because this method is only one part of largest application, so I would like to ask you about the possibility of modifying the current code.

Comment: Not really sure what kind of help you are looking for. Clearly site you trying to use requires cookies and does not work correctly if cookies are not supported. You already know solution ("everything works fine until the cookies are turned off")... Please [edit] post to clarify what type of answers you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for tip and reply.
I think, that my request will be more clear now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be an incorrect sending of the request. I had to set the correct header in the request (origin) to avoid multiple redirects (which the **server** did only for me because it received the wrong request).

The code was correct.